# Use PHP to parse HTML page to get selected value from a dropdown list. Is it possible?

Tags: php, javascript, html, dom

I have a program that uploads a .csv file of golf scores. upon upload the data from the file is diplayed in the form of a html table in the browser. the code for this is shown below.

```
echo '<div class="tablediv"><table><form method="post" action="new.php" >';


while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($ctr ==1)
        {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<th>" . $data[3] . "</th><th>" .  $data[4] .
        "</th><th>  " .     $data[5] . "</th><th> " . $data[6].
        "</th><th>" . $data[7] ."</th><th> Prize </th>" ;
        echo '</tr>';
        $ctr++ ;
        }
        else if ($ctr > 1) 
        {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" .$data[9] . "</td><td>" .  $data[10] .
       "</td><td>" . $data[11] . "</td><td>  " . $data[12]. "</td><td>" . $data[13] . "</td><td><select name='dropdown'>
        <option value='empty'>None Allocated</option>
        <option value='firstprize'>First Prize</option>
        <option value='secondprize'>Second Prize</option>
        <option value='thirdprize'>Third Prize</option>
        </select></td>";
        echo '</tr>';
        }

    }
    echo '<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" class="submit1" /></form></table></div></br>';

fclose($handle);
}
```

once a user has uploaded the file and it is diplayed I want the user to be able to allocate a prize via the dropdown list and then, once this is done the data can be commited to a database. what i need to do is basically get the selected prize position also and commit that to the database along with the other data. im just not too sure how to get at the selected value in the dropdown list. would the best way to do this be to use PHP simple HTML DOM parser? or does anyone know of an easier way. Thanks a lot for your help in advance!

the initial upload of the file looks like below. last column being the dropdownlist

```
 Player name    H'cap   Score   Front   Back    Prize
 name           18        66    33.0    33.0    none allocated
 name           11        67    33.5    33.5    none allocated
 name           4         67    33.0    34.0    none allocated
 name           12        67    31.0    36.0    none allocated
 name           11        68    34.5    33.5    none allocated
 name           6         68    34.0    34.0    none allocated
 name           19        68    31.5    36.5    none allocated
 name           11        69    36.5    32.5    none allocated
 name           11        69    33.5    35.5    none allocated
```

Comment: Stop right there! You're thinking too complicated. What you want is a form which contains the dropdown and submits its data to a PHP script. No need to parse any HTML.

Comment: +1 , i have nothing left to say

Comment: okay thanks Carsten. I usually over complicate my solutions. i shall give it a go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

my solution was this. this way i can get the post data on the new.php page by using var_dump($_POST). I create another counter "$counter2" and initialize it to 1. then in append the counter to the dropdownlist name " and var_dump($_POST) gives me an output like 
this

```
 array(76) { ["dropdown1"]=> string(11) "secondprize"    
 ["dropdown2"]=> string(5) "empty" ["dropdown3"]=> string(10) "firstprize" 
 ["dropdown4"]=> string(5) "empty" ["dropdown5"]=> string(5) "empty"
```

here are the changes i made to the function.

```
    if ($this->fileerror > 0) {
    echo "Error: " . $this->fileerror . "<br />"; 
}else{ 
if (($handle = fopen($this->filetemp, "r")) !== FALSE) {
    $ctr = 1; // used to exclude the CSV header
            $count2 = 1;        
    echo '<div class="tablediv"><table><form method="post" action="new.php" >';

    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        if($ctr ==1)
        {

        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<th>" . $data[3] . "</th><th>" .  $data[4] . "</th><th>  " . $data[5] . "</th><th> " . $data[6]. "</th><th>" . $data[7] ."</th><th> Prize </th>" ;
        echo '</tr>';
        $ctr++ ;
        }
        else if ($ctr > 1) 
        {
        echo '<tr>';
        echo "<td>" .$data[9] . "</td><td>" .  $data[10] . "</td><td>" . $data[11] . "</td><td>  " . $data[12]. "</td><td>" . $data[13] . "</td><td><select name='dropdown" .  $count2."'>
        <option value='empty'>None Allocated</option>
        <option value='firstprize'>First Prize</option>
        <option value='secondprize'>Second Prize</option>
        <option value='thirdprize'>Third Prize</option>
        </select></td>";
        echo '</tr>';
        $count2++;
        }

    }
    echo '</br><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" /></form></table></div></br>';

fclose($handle);
}
```

this is a pretty sloppy solution i know. so any other solutions you may have for this would be appreciated. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I guess yes! You can do kind of this way:

```
echo "<td>" .$data[9] . "</td><td>" .  $data[10] .
       "</td><td>" . $data[11] . "</td><td>  " . $data[12]. "</td><td>" . $data[13] . "</td><td><select>
        <option value='empty'", ($prize == "None") ? ' class="selected"' : '',">None Allocated</option>
        <option value='firstprize'", ($prize == "First Prize") ? ' class="selected"' : '',">First Prize</option>
        <option value='secondprize'", ($prize == "Second Prize") ? ' class="selected"' : '',">Second Prize</option>
        <option value='thirdprize'", ($prize == "Third Prize") ? ' class="selected"' : '',">Third Prize</option>
        </select></td>";
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Carsten said, you don't need to overcomplicate this. You can easily get the value from a dropdown:

```
<form action="page.php" method="post">
<select name="example">
        <option value='empty'>None Allocated</option>
        <option value='firstprize'>First Prize</option>
        <option value='secondprize'>Second Prize</option>
        <option value='thirdprize'>Third Prize</option>
</select>
</form>

<!-- page.php -->

<?
    echo $_POST['example'];
```

If you select 'Second Prize' it will echo 'secondprize'

Comment: thanks Andy. but each line printed in the while loop has a dropdown list and i dont want to put a submit button after each line. maybe im missing something here but i cant get the <form> post the data to another page this way.

Comment: alright i changed it around a bit. and now im just getting out the last dropdownlist value on the page i post to. using echo var_dump($_POST['dropdown']) as the dropdownlists are all named "dropdown in the while loop. maybe if i use a int to name all the dropdown lists differently? its not ideal but may work

Comment: so my not ideal solution worked. this way i can just echo var_dump($_POST).  i get all the selected prizes by the user. i will edit the above code. but they maybe an easier way of doing it.

Comment: instead for `name="example"` do `name="example[$i]"` where `$i` is the key of your 'loop'. This will mean in the PHP file, `$_POST['example']` will be an array mapping `$i` to the value that particular dropdown had selected. Sorry for the late reply